# Adding dll reference to Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, dll, activexobject

Could anyone please suggest a option for adding a DLL reference in Javascript. I'm working on a javascript app in which we are trying to get events from server directly without .Net/Java. I've tried using ActiveXObject, but it is not supported in current browsers

Comment: Not possible. Think the security issues such a feature would cause.

Answer (score 3):

> but it is not supported in current browsers

You can't do this in a browser. The browser implements a security-sandboxed environment. It used to be that you could write "NSAPI plugins" to do this, but browsers stopped supporting them years ago because of security issues. (And as you say, IE used to support ActiveX on Windows, but even IE backed off it except in certain Enterprise situations, and no other browser ever supported it.)